# convergence in a special sequense

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

If $(a_{n})$ is a decreasing sequence which is positive for all $n$ and the series $a_{1}+a_{2}+a_{3}+...$ is divergent:prove this sequence is convergent to one 
$(a_{1}+a_{3}+...+a_{2n-1})/(a_{2}+a_{4}+...+a_{2n})$
i have tried solving this a couple of times but had no luck
at first i tried to list when a decreasing  sequence is divergent but i couldn't match the result with the rest of the assumptions and it has been a while since i have had this at the back of my mind so if you have any input 
your help would be appreciated.

Comment: Consider $-a_1+a_{2n+1}$ on the numerator.